# Kendo UI radial gauge start max number first

Tags: kendo-ui

is it possible to go from high number to low number in the Kendo UI Radial gauge?  I know I can use reverse but the meter then starts from the right side instead of the left.  If there a way to have the numbers in the gauge go from max to min and have the meter start from the left side?

Comment: do you mind having the value stay 0-max and just having the labels reversed? if so, use a label template: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uYuKu

Comment: Thanks @ezanker, that worked great

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you add the labels yourself in the gauge's background image using a graphic program.  Then turn off the visibility of the labels.